ASP.NET MapStaticAssets does not serve files installed by LibMan
I have a website in ASP.NET. After I upgraded to .NET 9 and replaced UseStaticFiles with MapStaticAssets, I noticed that the server returns an HTTP 404 error if the client tries  to request library files from the /wwwroot/lib directory managed by the LibMan (Library Manager). I have Install Client-Side Libraries on Build enabled.
This workaround works for me:
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
 FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "lib")),
 RequestPath = "/lib"
});

app.MapStaticAssets();

However, I didn't expect MapStaticAssets to not work for static files delivered by LibMan. If I debug it locally on my computer, the error doesn't appear.
Am I misunderstanding something?
Update
The production app is hosted on Azure in the Web App service with Windows OS and the .NET version set to .NET 9 (STS).

could you share what's your production environment? locally its works maybe the configuration and behavior of the app is different than the production. in your workaround you have explicitly set the path so it should work. i also made test locally which is working fine
